# Custom Layout for scanner activity using zxing library

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I have an android activity which can scan a QR code in android.

```
public class ScannerActivity extends CaptureActivity {

   private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
   ResultHandler resultHandler;
   Parameters parameters;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
      super.onCreate(state);

     IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);

     integrator.setPrompt("Place the code in the center of the square.\n         It will be scanned automatically.");

     integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
  //  integrator.setCaptureLayout(R.layout.qrscanner_layout);
     integrator.setCaptureActivity(ScannerActivityOrientation.class);
     integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
     integrator.initiateScan();
  }
}
```

I have include these libraries in my gradle file.

```
 zxing_core            : "com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1",
 zxing_android         : "com.google.zxing:android-core:3.2.1",
 zxing_embedded        : "com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.1.0@aar",
```

I have a simple layout file.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerHeadLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal|left"
    android:background="@color/menu_blue"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerMainContent"
    style="@style/activityContent"
    android:layout_below="@id/containerHeadLine"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to set  a custom layout for the scanner. 
The method

```
 integrator.setCaptureLayout(R.layout.qrscanner_layout);
```

Doesn’t resolve for me. Some help please.

Answer (score 1):

include these libraries in your `gradle` file.

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'

compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:2.3.0@aar'

compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-legacy:2.3.0@aar'

compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-integration:2.3.0@aar'
```